# I have a bunch of GDI/GDI+ questions

Tags: gdi+

Just want to know if there's a forum dedicated to GDI/GDI+ or Windows graphics manipulation? Many thanks...

Comment: Just the one forum here. Be sure to tag your questions with GDI or GDI+ and also Windows or Win32 and C or C++ if that's relevant. Also you can search Stack Overflow for existing questions with specific tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Bob Powells GDI FAQ at [web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx), there is loads of infromation on his site that has helped me out.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. That helps some. But I am looking for a dedicated place to ask my own questions.